# C close both pipes at the end of execution of a process

Tags: c, pipe

I made a program in C, where the father communicates with the child, and the child communicates with the father through 2 pipes respectively.

It works perfect.

The father closes the read end of one pipe and also closes the write end of the other pipe.
Same goes for the son, just changing what to close in each pipe.

The theoretical question is:

when the all the children finish their executing, and the father is about to exit successfully, should i close the other two sides of type?

Is it really necessary?  And why? I just want to understand better the whole structure of the program.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using the stdin and stdout pipes of the child?

Comment: I am not using the stdin and stdout of the child. I am using the stdout of the father to print the result on a certain file.

Answer (score 1):

When you exit the program any open files will be `close`d automatically. 
You can close it explicitly of course, and if you want to do any special error handling you should close it explicitly so you can check the return value of `close()`.

As you are probably aware, `close()` will return an error if the disk is full and there is data that has not yet been `flush`ed.